# Auto refreshing using setInterval function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to auto refresh a page after every certain period of time which will be provided by the user.I have made the code which is reloading the page only once.what may be the problem?

Here is my code:

```
function refreshmethod(){
    var myvalue = document.getElementById('mytextBox').value;
    if(myvalue <= 0){
        alert('Please enter a positive value in the input');
        return;         
    }
    setInterval(function(){ window.location.reload(); }, myvalue * 1000);           
}
```

Comment: How do you call your function `refreshMethod` ?

Comment: after reloading first time page, thie mehod how is called again? refreshmethod

Comment: Also store that value somewhere (like localStorage), otherwise it will be wiped every time page is reloaded.

Comment: Also it's reloading the page, which resets the code execution (it's basically a new page with blank values). `setTimeout` would be better suited. What would you like to have refreshed? [tag:AJAX] is invented for this kind of stuff.

Comment: you need to make var myvalue = document.getElementById('mytextBox').value; as static otherwise it will get undefined when the page refreses.

Comment: What is the need to reload the page though? Why are you doing it?!

Answer (score 3):

When you reload the page, any scripts that were running during the previous load are stopped, so `setInterval` functions no longer continue.

You can save the refresh period in `sessionStorage`. When the page loads, it can check to see if this is set, and schedule another reload.

```
function auto_refresh() {
    var saved_refresh = sessionStorage.getItem("refresh");
    if (saved_refresh) {
        setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(); }, saved_refresh * 1000);
    }
}
window.onload = auto_refresh;

function refreshmethod(){
    var myvalue = document.getElementById('mytextBox').value;
    if(myvalue <= 0){
        alert('Please enter a positive value in the input');
        return;         
    }
    setTimeout(function(){ window.location.reload(); }, myvalue * 1000); 
    sessionStorage.setItem("refresh", myValue);       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function refreshmethod(){
var myvalue =   document.getElementById('mytextBox').value;
if(myvalue <= 0){
    alert('Please enter a positive value in the input');
    return;         
}
if(!localStorage.getItem("item1")=“go”){
localStorage.getItem("item1",”go”);
}
if(localStorage.getItem("item1",”go”)){
    setInterval(function(){ window.location.reload(); }, myvalue * 1000);     }
}
```

I use my mobile so may be error with this code check it but the whole idea is to use 
Local storage set and get

Answer (score 0):

A tinier solution:

*(unfortunately, for understandable security reasons, we can't build a code snippet…)*

```js
  function refreshMethod(every){
      console.log(every);
      if (every <= 0) { return alert('Please enter a positive value in the input') }
      sessionStorage.setItem('laps', every);
      setInterval(function(){ window.location.reload(); }, every * 1000);           
  }

  try { refreshMethod(sessionStorage.getItem('laps')) }
  catch(error){}
```

```html
<p>Input a value and exit the field (with tab)</p>
<input type="text" name="mytextBox" value="" id="mytextBox" onchange="refreshMethod(this.value)">
```